# How we can get response from Helper class to component and bind with HTML in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-services

In below is the **AppointmentHelper** class I have created

```
export class AppointmentHelper {

public static bindAssessements(servicedata: any,
    appointmentService: AppointmentService,
    serviceDeliveryGuid: string): any {
    appointmentService.getAssessments(serviceDeliveryGuid)
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response && response.data) {
            this.servicedata = response.data
        }
    }, () => {
      // Error Block
    });
  }
}
```

In my main component i am trying to call helper class like the below

```
ngOnInit() {   
  servicedata :any;
    this.serviceDeliveryGuid = '13c22f96-163e-40cf-b13a-e6832154d985';
    AppointmentHelper.bindAssessements(this.servicedata, this.appointmentService, this.serviceDeliveryGuid);
  }
```

But i am unable to get the data from helper class.

So could you please suggest me how we can get response from Helper class to component and bind with HTML in angular 7?

Comment: You mean you are not getting `response.data`? Try logging in *Error block*

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistype in:

```
public static bindAssessements(servicedata: any,
    appointmentService: AppointmentService,
    serviceDeliveryGuid: string): any {
    appointmentService.getAssessments(serviceDeliveryGuid)
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response && response.data) {
            // here should be servicedata = response.data
            this.servicedata = response.data
        }
    }, () => {
      // Error Block
    });
  }
}
```

also

```
ngOnInit() {   
  servicedata :any; // why? you also using this.servicedata in function call
  ...
}
```

have you linked servicedata in template?

```html
<span>{{ servicedata }}</span>
```

Comment: even if we use servicedata = response.data also not binding data in HTMl

Comment: but there is no code to reflect servicedata to template. If you have it - show us :)